# Get collection of ASP.Net validators in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I'm essentially trying to disable all RequiredFieldValidators on a page using the function ValidatorValidate(id, boolean) however my first step would be to get a collection of all the validators on the page and then filter them down to just the RequiredFieldValidators.

I'd like to do this using javascript only if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function DisbaleAllValidators() {
    if (typeof Page_Validators != 'undefined') {
        for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
            if (Page_Validators[i] != null) {
                ValidatorEnable(Page_Validators[i], false);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**Update:**

According to MSDN docs, you cannot differentiate between the types of validators on the client-side.  However, you could try assigning the requiredfieldvalidators a css class - and then checking to see if the validator is of that class.  Untested: code:

```
if ($(Page_Validators[i]).hasClass("classname")) {  
    ValidatorEnable(Page_Validators[i], false);
}
```

Comment: Thank for you answer, do you know how to explicitly disable just those which are RequiedFieldValidators? The solution you posted above is for validators of all type from what I can see

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the required field validators by checking for the evaluation function name (this example uses `<function>.toString()` because `<function>.name` isn't supported in IE8):

```
if(Page_Validators[i].evaluationfunction.toString().indexOf('RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid') != -1) {
     // Do stuff here
```